# Facebook Graph API : find friends in a place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use graph API Facebook to get list of a place I have been there (https://graph.facebook.com/myuserid/feed?with=location) and return place id. And I want to know my facebook friends that ever been there too by place id. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really available in the Graph API. What is possible is to get the friends which have been tagged at a specific `place_id`.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page.context/friends_tagged_at

But even there you have the restriction that

> Only friends who use the requesting app will be returned.